# I want to create an HTML template guide for designers, is there pre-existing materials to help with this?

Tags: html

I use number of designers to create HTML templates from PSD designs. What I would like to receive back is a html page containing the most common HTML elements and how they will render based on the derived CSS and HTML. Essentially the content of the page would be common amongst the templates but it would be a key aide in seeing how the various elements from H1 to H6, form elements and ul/ol etc would look with that template and css.

Is there a name for this sort of skeleton file or are there examples of this out there, I cant find anything on the googles.

Many thanks for your help :-)

S

Comment: The closest term that springs to mind, off the back of your 'skeletal' remark is `wire-framing` - there are wire-framing applications available, paid for, free, SSaS et cetera, I'm just not sure of the options available that are fitting to your situation. Check it out.

Comment: So, you want a template to help you build a template? There's a 'Yo Dawg' joke just waiting to happen..

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something along the lines of this?
http://snipplr.com/view/8121/html-test-page-for-css-style-guide/

From what it sounds like, you want something that goes from PSD -> test html template? I am unfamiliar with PSD, but you should be able to just strip the CSS and toss it into a test page like the above.

If you want to test the html and css you just view it in a browser.

If you are using a standard CMS often they have empty templates filled with "Lorem Ipsum" which will allow you to see how the styles work in the CMS.